# Uncaught Reference Error addMarker is not defined

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to use the Google Maps API to add markers onto my map. I am calling the addMarker function in my application.html.erb in script tags and I cant work out why the function is not defined when it exists in my map.js.

Take a look at the code below, I am sure it is something obvious, but I am new to web development and have been searching the web for a long time and cant see what I am doing wrong.

Thanks so much!

This is my map.js......

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

}

 function addMarker(latitude, longitude, title) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position:new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude), 
          map : map, 
          title : title
        });
      }



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


});
```

This is my application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>EventsMapper</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> -->
  <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC74gnSe7p17ulcZUzgPJHxYurGg2bjRYg&sensor=false">
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function() {
      // initMap();

      //add here var items that converts ToDoItems to JSON, take out the var to make to global

      <% Yoga.all.each do |item| %>

      addMarker(<%=item.latitude%>, <%=item.longitude%>, '<%=item.name%>');
      <%end%>
     });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
   <!--  <input type="text" id="autocomplete"> -->
   <div id='googlemap'>
    <div id="map-canvas">
    </div>
  </div>

    <%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your add marker function is written inside document ready function. Remove the function from document ready scope and place it outside.

Comment: Thank you very much, that sorted it out!

Comment: I want to accept it, but I cant work out how to, I have tried to vote up your answer, but it will only let me do that if I have 15 reputation. Is there another way to do it??

Comment: Sorry this is stupid, but I am not sure how to accept an answer. I have tried to vote it up, but says I require a 15 reputation!

Comment: There is a tick mark just below the down arrow of answer. Click on that tick mark will mark the answer accepted